# A way to get an exact scale from a GeoServer OpenLayers preview

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I use the maps to create tiles at certain scales but want to be able to view that particular scale in the OpenLayers preview but GeoServer has its own set scales on the zoom levels such as:

1:67
1:133
1:266 etc increasing as you zoom out.

Is there a way to change these default values to set scales at zoom levels? Or even changing the getmap request manually?

Comment: Don't use the preview to view tiles, use the tile viewer instead

Comment: Not familiar with the tile viewer, where would I find this and would the tile viewer give the exact scales needed?

Comment: Under the tiles menu

Comment: I use the preview to see what the objects/layers will look like once they are tiles not to actually see the tiles in the layer preview, what am trying to achieve is the exact scale on the previews, whether it be tile viewer or layer preview, the scales are predefined when zooming at different levels. Is there a way to change the scales at different zoom levels so I can 100% confirm what the tile will look at a specific scale. E.g 1:1250 or 1:2500 etc.

Comment: No, use QGIS or other program to look at specific scales - the tile viewer should pick good values based on your zoom settings for the layer